# Plotting predicted effects: extract upper and lower bounds from {effects} package command

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, glm, effects

I've got a logistic regression model and was trying to get a predicted probabilities plot for a dichotomous predictor `x1` (which is "gender"). Now there's a straightforward way by simply using the `effects`-package:

```
dat<-data.frame(
  y=round(runif(100,0,1)),
  x1=as.factor(round(runif(100,0,1))),
  x2=round(runif(100,20,80))
)

model<-glm(data=dat,
           formula=y~x1+x2, 
           family=binomial(link="logit"))

require(effects)
plot(Effect("x1",model))
```

This returns:

[image]

But since this is not very fancy and it would be nice to do this in ggplot: Is there a way to extract the upper and lower bounds from `Effect("x1",model)`? The command by itself only returns the predicted effect of a person being a man or woman, but does not yield the 95% upper and lower bounds. And there is no mention in `?effects`.

What I need is a frame like this so I can let `ggplot` do the job:

```
x1   effect   lower   upper
1    0.39     .       .
0    0.56     .       .
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't expect that this would be so easy. Apparently it suffices to write `summary()` around the effects command.

```
summary(Effect("x1",model))


#x1 effect
x1
        0         1 
0.5572423 0.3984501 

#Lower 95 Percent Confidence Limits
x1
        0         1 
0.4111167 0.2782799 

#Upper 95 Percent Confidence Limits
x1
        0         1 
0.6940889 0.5322441
```